# Opening iTunes Store via URL scheme with no album

Tags: iphone, xcode, url-scheme

I am working on developing a music player app. If the user has no audiobooks or podcasts, I am showing a button, which takes user to iTunes store just like it happens in the native music player app.

I looked at the url scheme to open the iTunes Store app in the developers guide and it looks like this:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://phobos.apple.com/WebObjects/MZStore.woa/wa/viewAlbum?i=156093464&id=156093462&s=143441"]];
```

what it does is, it open the iTunes store with that specific album, I don't want t open the store with a specific album. So I tried removing the album params as:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://phobos.apple.com/WebObjects/MZStore.woa/wa/viewAlbum?"]];
```

but with this, I get an alert that your request could not be completed, maybe because iTunes store can not find any album.

So is there anyway I can open the iTunes Store without passing album details, or maybe opening the search tab of iTunes Store

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you can just do the following to launch the 'Music' tab of the iTunes app:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString@"http://itunes.apple.com"]];
```

Comment: Thanks Programming Thomas. Actually I wanted to open up Podcast/Audiobooks tab, but your answer helped me in getting there.. so what I did was changed the urlstring to http://itunes.apple.com/podcasts and http://itunes.apple.com/audiobooks and it worked like charm!
Thanks :)